# How to solve $|1-\cos(x)| < \frac{1}{2}10^{-8}$ for $x$?

Tags: calculus, trigonometry, inequality

How to solve $|1-\cos(x)| < \frac{1}{2}10^{-8}$ for x? Can you show me the steps? The answer should be that $-10^{-4}\leq x \leq 10^{-4}$ but I am not sure why.Or $-\arccos(\frac{199999999}{200000000}) \leq x \leq \arccos(\frac{199999999}{200000000})$. I get that $\arccos(\frac{200000001}{200000000}) \leq x \leq \arccos(\frac{199999999}{200000000})$ which is not the same.

Here is what I did [(few steps)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4rvNv.png):
\begin{array}{l}
-\left(\frac{1}{2} \cdot 10^{-8}\right) \leq 1-\cos (x) \leq \frac{1}{2} \cdot 10^{-8} \\
-\left(\frac{1}{2} \cdot 10^{-8}\right)-1 \leq-\cos (x) \leq \frac{1}{2} \cdot 10^{-8}-1 \\
\left(\frac{1}{2} \cdot 10^{-8}\right)+1 \leq \cos (x) \leq \frac{-1}{2} \cdot 10^{-8}+1
\end{array}

And yes, I am aware that the solution applies for every cycle of cos - that is, $2\pi$

Comment: Replace $\cos(x)$ with the first 2 terms of its Taylor series around $x=0$

Comment: For positive $x$, you have $0\le 1-\cos x<\frac{x^2}2$. So it suffices to ensure that $\frac{x^2}2<\frac12\,10^{-8}$.

Comment: @BernardMassé Can't you solve it without Taylor series?

Comment: @Bernard Why does that inequality hold? Also, can't you solve this inequality without Taylor series?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your three steps\begin{array}{l}
-\left(\frac{1}{2} \cdot 10^{-8}\right) \leq 1-\cos (x) \leq \frac{1}{2} \cdot 10^{-8} \\
-\left(\frac{1}{2} \cdot 10^{-8}\right)-1 \leq-\cos (x) \leq \frac{1}{2} \cdot 10^{-8}-1 \\
\left(\frac{1}{2} \cdot 10^{-8}\right)+1 \leq \cos (x) \leq \frac{-1}{2} \cdot 10^{-8}+1
\end{array}
the second step to third step is *wrong*! This is because $-a\le-b$ should become $a\ge b$. In fact $\cos(x) \le 1$ always, so how can $\epsilon +1 \le \cos x$ for any $\epsilon > 0$? You can just toss that side of the inequality from the start:
\begin{align}
-\cos (x) &\leq \frac{1}{2} \cdot 10^{-8}-1 \\
\iff \left(\frac{-1}{2} \cdot 10^{-8}\right)+1 &\leq \cos (x)
\end{align}
Working first only in the first quadrant i.e. $0\le x\le\pi/2$, applying $\arccos$ which is is decreasing, we get
$$ 0\le x \le \arccos \left(\left(\frac{-1}{2} \cdot 10^{-8}\right)+1\right)$$
Then, as $\cos$ is even, it holds also for
$$ -\arccos \left(\left(\frac{-1}{2} \cdot 10^{-8}\right)+1\right) \le x \le 0$$
i.e. $$|x|\le \arccos \left(\left(\frac{-1}{2} \cdot 10^{-8}\right)+1\right).$$
Accounting for the periodicity, you should see
$$\left\{ x\in\mathbb R : \exists k\in\mathbb Z  \text{ such that }|x-2k\pi |\le \arccos \left(\left(\frac{-1}{2} \cdot 10^{-8}\right)+1\right)\right\}.$$

PS the Taylor series solution in the comments is only approximate, and will leave out some values of $x$.

Here is a [graph](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/fknkmhkt6t) verifying the method. If you use $10^{-8}/2$  there will be nothing shown on the screen since it's so small, so I replaced it with a bigger value. The red and green areas define the same range of $x$ values, but using the first two Taylor terms results in a slightly smaller region:

[image]

Comment: ahhh yesyes that is the answer I was hoping to see(not that I do not enjoy and appreciate other answers showing other ways to solve the problem, I really do)! Thanks! You say "PS the Taylor series solution is only approximate" - but this is not using Taylor series, is it? That will also mean this is not "just" an approximation, correct?

Comment: @Tihi, yes, I'm just pointing out that the commenters' suggestion to use Taylor series will result in a **sufficient** but not **necessary** condition. This set is the precise exact answer, until you evaluate the arccos and then it depends on your numerical accuracy

Comment: Now that I am reading it again, I have a question: From the start, you choose to deal with  RIGHT inequality which then logically leads to both upper and lower bounds for x. But if you dealt with the inequality $-\left(\frac{1}{2} \cdot 10^{-8}\right)-1 \leq-\cos (x)$, you would not get the same(I think) - because $-\left(\frac{1}{2} \cdot 10^{-8}\right)-1 \neq \left(\frac{1}{2} \cdot 10^{-8}\right)-1$. So how can you argue why you chose one inequality over the other?

Comment: So basically what I am saying is that I do not see how you would end up with the same answer if you started using the left part of the initial inequality instead of the right part.

Comment: @Tihi i made no choices. The other inequality is just useless, because $1-\cos x \ge 0$ is always true and doesn’t restrict any values of $x$.

Comment: but how is $-\left(\frac{1}{2} \cdot 10^{-8}\right) \leq 1-\cos (x)$ the same as $0 \leq 1 - cos(x)$?

Comment: @Tihi I’m thinking of a number bigger than or equal to zero. If I now tell you that the number is also bigger than $-10^{-8}/2$, is it any easier to guess what number I’m thinking of? (Spoiler: no)

Comment: @Tihi if you prefer math than analogy: the solution set of $a\le f(x) \le b$ is the intersection of the solution sets for $a\le f(x) $ and $ f(x)\le b$. In this case, the solution set of &a\le f(x)$ is all real numbers, because $a<0$ and $f(x)>0$. Intersecting with the set of all real numbers does nothing.

Comment: Ahhh yes of course. Thank you so much. You helped me a lot! I really appreciate it. Have a very good day!!!!!

Comment: @Tihi you're welcome, and the same to you! If you think an answer is useful, you should vote it up to let others know they can trust it :)

Answer (score 2):

Using
$$ 1-\cos x=2\sin^2(\frac x2) $$
one changes the inequality into
$$ \sin^2(\frac x2)<\frac14 10^{-8} $$
or
$$ -\frac12 10^{-4}<\sin(\frac x2)<\frac12 10^{-4} $$
So
$$ -2\arcsin(\frac12 10^{-4})<x<2\arcsin(\frac12 10^{-4})$$

Comment: Ahh, interesting way, thank you! Glad that you provided a way that did not require Taylor series :) Can you figure out what I did wrong in the few steps I linked? I do not get the same, as mentioned in the OP

Comment: After the 3 steps shown, I would just take arccos of all sides which would then result in the inequality mentioned in the OP which is different from the actual/correct answer(as given in your answer also)

Comment: The last step is wrong. It should be $$\frac{-1}{2} \cdot 10^{-8}+1 \leq \cos (x) \leq  \left(\frac{1}{2} \cdot 10^{-8}\right)+1$$

Answer (score 0):

$$
1 - \cos x = \frac{x^2} 2 + \text{higher-order terms}
$$
When $x$ is tiny, the higher-order terms are negligible, so solve $ \dfrac {x^2} 2 < \tfrac 1 2 \times 10^{-8}$ for $x.$